# MySQL filter results by month and year

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My table shows the amount of searches taken by various countries and the date on which they were taken, I want a query that shows me the searches taken each month for both the years 2012 & 2013, I will need to add separate columns for month, year and number of searches. I have previously used the query below which returns the amount of searches taken each week, but I would like to change it to just the searches taken each month for years 2012 & 2013.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,
      `region`, 
       DATE(NOW()) as `week_ending` 
   FROM my_stores.stats 
        WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) 
               AND 
              `date` < DATE(NOW()) 
 GROUP BY `region`, DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,
      `region`, 
       YEAR(`date`) as `year`,
       MONTH(`date`)  as `month`
   FROM my_stores.stats 
        WHERE  YEAR(`date`) in (2012,2013)
 GROUP BY `region`, YEAR(`date`),MONTH(`date`)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,
      `region`, 
       MONTH(`date`),
       YEAR(`date`)
FROM my_stores.stats 
GROUP BY `region`, MONTH(`date`), YEAR(`date`);
```

Comment: Where condition is missing for year

Comment: Yes i know ;-), see the answer of valex.