# Mysql YEAR function not supported?

Tags: mysql

Display the CName, Bank Name and dateofopen for all the customers whose account is opened in 1998

```
SELECT CName, BankName,dateofopen FROM bank where dateofopen = YEAR(1968);
```

I tried with this query but getting error YEAR function not supported

I'm working on mysql terminal

Comment: I'm prompted to say by typing the query in any mysql client will do. What you need is a select with a simple where criterion. Start with some basic sql tutorials or you with your book on sql in the school.

Comment: I need function which select only year i know with php what is function for mysql?

Comment: year function is not supported by mysql terminal

Comment: @sHASHI    could be that  1968 is not a valida date  try using  '1968-01-01'

Comment: i need to compare only year, how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL filter results by month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723905/mysql-filter-results-by-month-and-year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CName, BankName,YEAR(dateofopen) FROM bank where YEAR(dateofopen) = 1968;
```